# Library Mismatch Issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber

My `Spring-boot` Application worked perfectly until I began fiddling with spring boot and cucumber testing. Can't say exactly what went wrong but from my research it seems to be a library dependency mismatch in my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>EmploymentBootCamp</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EmploymentBootCamp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot Employment Boot Camp</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>EmploymentBootCamp.demo.EmploymentBootCampApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>EmploymentBootCamp.demo.EmploymentBootCampApplication</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error I get is down below

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:55) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>       at EmploymentBootCamp.demo.EmploymentBootCampApplication.main(EmploymentBootCampApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       ... 25 common frames omitted

Comment: Seems to me more of a missing dependency rather than a mismatched versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can safely remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

via *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* you already have a transitive dependency to *spring-tx*.

By explicitly binding *spring-tx* to the *test-scope*, you remove it from the *compile-scope* (mavens default scope)

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a whole lot of head ache